# Nexus 5 screen no working, how do i recover data

Tags: data-recovery

My nexus 5 screens LCD had broken so I ordered a new one and installed it, it's not the first time I have done it, and for some reason, it won't display anything to the screen, I know my phone is working because the LED is on and sounds play. I don't believe that I can get the screen to work, I'm assuming there's an issue with the board since it seemed to be doing the same thing after I broke the previous screen. My concern at this point is that I would like to recover the data on my phone but I'm not sure how to go about it, The power button on it has been broken for a long time so I've just been using the Android SDK to turn my phone on but i cant figure out how to recover anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Just plugging it should allow you to get your data, if you mean the application data, that’s going to be extremely tough.  I suggest using your choice of professional data recover service

Comment: Maybe you want to connect a screen using HDMI. There are dongles allowing that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `adb` working, you could just pull everything from the /sdcard directory which is either your internal storage if no actual SD card is installed or the actual SD card that is installed (/sdcard is an alias)

Anyways you can use `adb` and the pull command:

```
adb pull /sdcard .
```

That will pull everything on the /sdcard which could be a lot.

Some common file locations:

Screenshots

```
adb pull /sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots .
```

Pictures & videos taken with the camera:

```
adb pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera .
```

Downloads folder:

```
adb pull /sdcard/Download
```

Also you could create a backup of your device, but you'd need to enter some information and tap a button to continue:

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all
```

So that's probably not for you...